# How to see xmpp messages in xml format in android logcat?

Tags: android, xml, format, xmpp, message

I am working on android chat application. I am using openfire and aSmack for it.
I am able to see the message with getBody() method.
I want to see the message in xml format, in which xmpp server send it in android logcat.

This is my message receive code :

```
public void receiveMessage(XMPPConnection xmppConnection) {

    if (xmppConnection != null) {

        PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
        xmppConnection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {

            @Override
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {

                Message message = (Message) packet;
                if (message.getBody() != null) {

                    Log.i("Received message:", message.getBody());
                }
            }
        }, filter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `toXML()` method for print the xmpp xml tag

e.g.

```
Message message = (Message) packet;
if (message.getBody() != null) 
{
    Log.i("Received message:", message.toXML());
}
```

for more details https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/4.1.0/javadoc/